# React.DOM.p(null, message) - explain null?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Anyone know what the `null` is in this line:

```
React.DOM.p(null, message);
```

I'm aware it's a convenience wrapper around `createElement`, i.e.

```
ReactElement createElement(
  string/ReactClass type,
  [object props],
  [children ...]
)
```

but am struggling to understand why the `type` is `null`.

The same would go for this line here:

```
React.DOM.div(null, 'Hello World!')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These functions are commonly referred to as [factories](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/glossary.html#factories) meaning they are functions that generate `ReactElements` with a particular type property.

This is roughly how these factories are created under the hood:

```
function createFactory(type) {
  return React.createElement.bind(null, type);
}
```

Which returns `React.createElement` as a bound function with `this` bound to `null` and `type` bound to whatever was passed in, allowing you to create shorthand instantiation functions for your elements:

```
// create a function that creates React <div> elements
let div = createFactory('div'); 

// create two divs using the div factory function
let div1 = div({ /* some props */ }, 'Div 1');
let div2 = div({ /* some props */ }, 'Div 2');
```

React already comes with built-in factories for common HTML tags such as `div`, `li` etc, which you have in your question.

---

> but am struggling to understand why the type is null.

Considering all of the above, when you look at one of your examples:

```
React.DOM.div(null, 'Hello World!')
```

The following happens:

`React.DOM.div` is just a factory function that under the hood passes `'div'` as the first argument to `React.createElement`, which is the type, and everything else gets passed as the remaining arguments.

Basic idea:

```
// the function is created as a factory
React.DOM.div = createFactory('div');

// and used to create a <div> element
var myDiv = React.DOM.div(null, 'Hello World');
```

This value of `div` as the first argument was setup in a similar manner as i've shown above whenever this factory was created.

Therefore, `null` in your case is just the `props` object, not the `type`. Type is bound to be `div` through the factory, meaning `props` is the first argument and `'Hello World!'` string is the `children` argument.

Comment: Great answer. In the last paragraph, I assume you mean 'div' is passed as the first argument to **createFactory**

Comment: Thanks, glad to help. Actually I do not think that, i've made an edit to clarify :)